# Website completely down after resizing boot disk VM (Google Cloud)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I had to resize the boot disk of my Debian Linux VM from 10GB to 30GB because it was full. After doing just so and stopping/starting my instance it has become useless. I can't enter SSH and i can't access my application. The last backups where from 1 month ago and we will lose A LOT of work if i don't get this to work.

I have read pretty much everything on the internet about resizing disks and repartitioning tables, but nothing seems to work.

When running `df -h` i see:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          36G   30G  5.8G  84% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        36G   30G  5.8G  84% /root
/dev/sdb1       4.8G   11M  4.6G   1% /home
overlayfs       1.0M  128K  896K  13% /etc/ssh/keys
tmpfs           848M  744K  847M   1% /run/metrics
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
overlayfs       1.0M  128K  896K  13% /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
tmpfs           848M     0  848M   0% /run/google/devshell
```

when running `sudo lsblk` i see:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   40G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1      35.9G  0 part /var/lib/docker
├─sda2    8:2    0   16M  1 part
├─sda3    8:3    0    2G  1 part
├─sda4    8:4    0   16M  0 part
├─sda5    8:5    0    2G  0 part
├─sda6    8:6       512B  0 part
├─sda7    8:7    0  512B  0 part
├─sda8    8:8        16M  0 part
├─sda9    8:9    0  512B  0 part
├─sda10   8:10   0  512B  0 part
├─sda11   8:11        8M  0 part
└─sda12   8:12   0   32M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0    5G  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0    5G  0 part /home
zram0   253:0    0  768M  0 disk [SWAP]
```

Before increasing the disk size i did try to add a second disk and i even formatted and mounted it following the google cloud docs, then unmounted it again. (so i edited the fstab and fstab.backup etc..)

Nothing about resizing disks / repartition tables on the google cloud documentation worked for me.. The `growpart`, `fdisk`, `resize2fs` and many other StackOverflow posts did neither.

When trying to access through SSH i get the "Unable to connect on port 22" error as stated here on the [google cloud docs](http://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror)

When creating a new Debian Linux instance with a new disk it works fine.

Anybody that can get this up and running for me without losing any data gets 100+ and a LOT OF LOVE......

Comment: please paste your console error message (boot message )to find out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to replicate the case scenario, but it didn't get me any VM instance issues.

I have created a VM instance with 10 GB of data and then Stopped it, increased the disk size to 30 GB and started the instance again. You mention that you can't ssh to the instance or access your application. After my test, I could ssh though and enter the instance. So there must be an issue of the procedure that you have followed that corrupted the VM instance or maybe the boot disk.

However there is a workaround to recover the files from the instance that you can't SSH to. I have tested it and it worked for me:

1. Go to Compute Engine page and then go to `Images`
2. Click on '[+] CREATE IMAGE'
3. Give that image a name and under `Source` select `Disk`
4. Under `Source disk` select the disk of the VM instance that you have resized.
5. Click on `Save`, if the VM of the disk is running, you will get an error. Either stop the VM instance first and do the same steps again or just select the box `Keep instance running (not recommended)`. (I would recommend to stop it first, as also suggested by the error).
6. After you save the new created image. Select it and click on `+ CREATE INSTANCE`
7. Give that instance a name and leave all of the settings as they are.
8. Under Boot Disk you make sure that you see the 30 GB size that you set up earlier when was increasing the disk size and the name should be the name of the image you created.
9. Click create and try to SSH to the newly created instance.
10. If all your files were preserved when you were resizing the disk, you should be able to access the latest ones you had before the corruption of the VM.

**UPDATE 2nd WORKAROUND - ATTACH THE BOOT DISK AS SECONDARY TO ANOTHER VM INSTANCE**

In order to attach the disk from the corrupted VM instance to a new GCE instance you will need to follow these steps :

1. Go to `Compute Engine > Snapshots` and click `+ CREATE SNAPSHOT`.
2. Under `Source disk`, select the disk of the corrupted VM. Create the snapshot.
3. Go to `Compute Engine > Disks` and click `+ CREATE DISK`.
4. Under `Source type` go to `Snapshot` and under `Source snapshot` chooce your new created snapshot from step 2. Create the disk.
5. Go to `Compute Engine > VM instances` and click `+ CREATE INSTANCE`.
6. Leave ALL the set up as defult. Under `Firewall` enable `Allo HTTP traffic` and `Allow HTTPS traffic`.
7. Click on `Management, security, disks, networking, sole tenancy`
8. Click on `Disks` tab.
9. Click on `+ Attach existing disk` and under `Disk` choose your new created disk. Create the new VM instnace.
10. SSH into the VM and run `$ sudo lsblk`
11. Check the device name of the newly attached disk and it’s primary partition (it will likely be /dev/sdb1)
12. Create a directory to mount the disk to: `$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/mount`
13. Mount the disk to the newly created directory `$ sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disks/mount`
14. Then you should be able to load all the files from the disk. I have tested it myself and I could recover the files again from the old disk with this method.

Comment: First of all, thanks for trying to help. I have followed your steps but on the new instance i get the exact same issue... I'm guessing the boot disk is corrupted?

Comment: I get the "Unable to connect on port 22" error when trying to enter ssh as stated here on gcloud docs https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror

Comment: The disk as it is, it is not corrupted. But it is a possibility that the boot files are, therefore you can't SSH into it. Cause the VM it self is running but the OS inside has issues. What you can do is to create a brand new VM instance, and attach the disk as secondary one to get your files. I have UPDATED my answer on how to do so.

Comment: With this method i can access the files but the files/folders are all empty and the images are 'zero bytes' any idea what it could be?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i can access the files but the files/folders are all empty and the images are 'zero bytes'". Are those the files of your website? if they are, then they are most probably corrupted. Also its a possibility that you are in a wrong username directory. So after the last step, you can run `$ cd /mnt/disks/mount` and then `$ ls`. You should see at least 3 username folders there. YOUR_USERNAME, datalab and ubuntu. Navigate to your username to find the files.

Comment: Let me know if the files you see are your website's files that are 'zero bytes' and confirm with me that you are in the right directory inside your mounted disk.

Comment: You were absolutely right, i was looking at the corrupted files as the wrong user. Your second workaround worked perfectly, i have got all my files back, thank you immensely. I will award you the bounty of 100 points in 23 hours when i'm allowed.

Comment: I am glad that you where able to recover your files. Thank you very much in advance for the points.